# Data is being written and called out of sync after POST

Tags: php, codeigniter, refresh, synchronization

I'm calling a view after an AJAX POST action. But I'm loading the view and calling Database data out of sync with the data being written. When I load the page, I look into the database and see the data there but it's not being rendered on the page. (I tried sessions and got the same problem). In order for the view to actually render the data from the database, I need to actually refresh the page. Same thing with the sessions, I need to refresh the page in order for the sessions data to render.  Is there a common reference to this kind of issue? I read about POSTBACK, is this something I need to look into further? It's basically a strange sync issue where the data is not being generated until I refresh the page and re-load it.

Comment: could you add some code?

Comment: I'm really just looking for a reference or a sample of how to handle PHP processing and View loading after POST. Basically, I have an `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` in my code to handle AJAX and it's being called and I'm loading the view after this condition but I need to refresh the page to actually see the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax call are async, by default. The javascript code continue without waiting for the return from the server.

So let look at :

```
 $.post('source.php',function(valueFromPHP){
    alert(valueFromPHP)
 });
 alert('Hello world')
```

In the previous example `Hello Wold` is alerted first, then the value from php.

If you want to insert the return value from php into your page you need to place all your code into the sucess function :

```
 $.post('source.php',function(valueFromPHP){
    alert(valueFromPHP)
    alert('Hello world')
 });
```

In the second example the value return from PHP is alerted first, then `Hello world`

So if you want to render the data received from php make sure you place your code inside the success function. Normally that is where we get error while working with jQuery ajax.

Let me know if it help!

Comment: Interesting, this is very insightful. I didn't have anything in the success. Will test with this new knowledge, +1'd it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Make sure that your PHP uses `print` or `echo` not `return` to write the data.

Comment: That's ok, I'll test it out and get back.